# Writing to char array, empty output

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reverse

I'm wondering what's occurring here, I allocate space for the dest variable outside of the reverse function. And then write to it in the function call. But my output is blank. I want to do this without malloc, purely for educational purposes. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*function declaration*/
void reverse(char *src, char *dest);

int main(void) {

char src[] = "hello, world";
char dest[strlen(src)];
reverse(src, dest);
printf("%s\n", dest);

return 0;
}

/*function reverse a string*/
void reverse(char *src, char *dest) {
int i;
int j = 0;
for(i = strlen(src); i >= 0; i--) {
  *(dest+j) = *(src+i);
  ++j;
  }
}
```

Comment: you know you can `dest[j] = src[i]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since your iteration starts with

```
for(i = strlen(src); i >= 0; i--) {
```

it assigns `0` to the dest, thus terminating the string. So printf() prints nothing as it sees the `0` terminator. You can re-write it as:

```
for(i = strlen(src) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  *(dest+j) = *(src+i);
  ++j;
  }
 dest[j] = 0; /* terminates the string */
```

2) You have another problem. Your `dest` doesn't have enough space. It should be:

```
char dest[strlen(src) + 1]; /* Notice the +1 */
```

3) You should use `size_t` for array indexes instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks, and why is size_t a preferable choice for array indexes?

Comment: `int` may not be able to hold all possible array indexes; while `size_t` can.

Comment: and `strlen()` returns a `size_t`. Right now you are probably getting a warning about implicit conversion from `size_t` to `int` (at least if you turn up the warning level).

Comment: There may not a warning if `size_t` happens to be `int`. Irrespective of warnings, always use the correct type, e.g. `size_t` for string functions if they return `size_t` (most of them do).

Comment: I'm not getting a warning and when I change both i and j to have type, size_t I get a segmentation fault...

Comment: @clcto Yes. But *not* necessarily `unsigned int`. It's just an unsigned type.

Comment: what do you mean by wrap around? Thanks

Comment: just having i by itself is equal to i != 0? Is this just syntactic sugar in c?

Comment: Wrap around: when `i` is `0` and if you do `i--` then it becomes the maximum value of size_t (`SIZE_MAX`). Let's say `SIZE_MAX` is `4294967295`. Then `i` becomes `4294967295` and then `4294967294` etc and the same goes on and the loop never exits.

Comment: @user2069328 I realized it won't work with that because you want to copy the value when `i=0` as well. You have to do something like this: http://ideone.com/nkMDEL or equivalent logic to ensure `src[0]` gets copied to `dest` and `i` doesn't get decrement below `0`.

Comment: Can you explain this to me? for(i = strlen(src) - 1; ; i--), how long will it decrement for? Without the conditional break, is it an infinite loop? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's an infinite loop without that break. But there's a break when `i==0` that's *after* the `src[0]` has been copied to `dest`.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting about the null character in your strings. `dest` is not large enough to hold the reverse of the string since there needs to be a null-terminator:

```
 char dest[ strlen(src) + 1 ];
```

Then in the loop you are copying the null-terminator to the front of the string so it is essentially the string `""` but using more memory. You need to start at the index `strlen() - 1`:

```
for(i = strlen(src)-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `for(i=strlen(src).....` in `reverse()`.  `src[strlen(src)]` is `0` (zero; string-termination).  So when you get to `printf()`, it sees the firs char and outputs an empty string.

Use `strlen(str)-1`, and then `*(dest+j) = 0` *after* the for-loop.

In total, `reverse()` should be:

```
void reverse(char *src, char *dest) {
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = strlen(src)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        *(dest+j) = *(src+i);
        ++j;
    }
    *(dest+j) = 0;
}
```